# How to use NFC in our application and how can we know that device supports NFC?

Tags: android, nfc

I have gone through some of the NFC related topics. But I did not find a clear and simple way to work with it or using NFC?

Another question is How can we recognize the device supports NFC or not,
Is there any code for that?

what makes it different from bluetooth?

All suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if device support NFC :

```
NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {

    //Yes NFC available 
}else{

   //Your device doesn't support NFC
}
```

And here is all for NFC : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

Comment: thanks, I also gone through that link. but could you please elaborate it more.

Comment: try with this link, there have more code for you :) : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278